# error in sql syntax? and in my c# img url string

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, html

Hi I have an sql syntax error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[User] u ON u.UserID = wp.UserID LEFT JOIN Pictures p ON p.UserID = u.UserID WHE' at line 1

My code:

```
using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT wp.WallPostings, p.PicturePath FROM WallPosting wp LEFT JOIN [User] u ON u.UserID = wp.UserID LEFT JOIN Pictures p ON p.UserID = u.UserID WHERE UserID=" + userId + " ORDER BY idWallPosting DESC", cn))
            {
                //("SELECT wp.WallPostings, p.PicturePath FROM WallPosting wp LEFT JOIN [User] u ON u.UserID = wp.UserID LEFT JOIN Pictures p ON p.UserID = u.UserID WHERE UserID=" + userId + " ORDER BY idWallPosting DESC", cn))
                using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    test1.Controls.Clear();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                        div.Attributes["class"] = "test";
                //div.Style["float"] = "left";

                        div.ID = "test";
                        Image img = new Image();
                        img.ImageUrl = String.Format("{1}", reader.GetString(0));
                        // this line needs to be represented in sql syntax
                        img.AlternateText = "Test image";

                        div.Controls.Add(img);
                        div.Controls.Add(ParseControl(String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0))));
                        div.Style["clear"] = "both";
                        test1.Controls.Add(div);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My database structure:

[image]

EDIT:

If i take the brackets out of the User in mysql syntax I then get an error:

**Column 'UserID' in where clause is ambiguous**

RE EDIT:

adding wp. to UserID in WHERE clause gives a new error:

**Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.**

Im sure this is due to this line:

```
img.ImageUrl = String.Format("{1}", reader.GetString(0));
```

Comment: Why adding brackets around `[User]` ?

Comment: Does the command work when not embedded in other code?  If you put in straight SQL in your database (with a value for your UserID), is the syntax correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserID exists in multiple tables so you have to fully qualify it in the WHERE clause.

```
          V
... WHERE wp.UserID= ...
          ^
```

Comment: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Comment: Try `img.ImageUrl = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(1));` It's the index on GetString that will get you the second column of your result set.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
WHERE UserID=
```

With this:

```
WHERE wp.UserID=
```

Answer (score 1):

You use both `Picture` and `User` in your query, both of which have a `UserId` column.  You'll need to tell your query which one to use.

Eg.

```
WHERE wp.UserId =
```

**EDIT 1**

Also,

In your `String.Format` calls, replace `"{1}"` with `"{0}"`.  `"{1}"` tells Format to look for the 2nd value you're passing, not the first (since it's zero based).

**EDIT 2**

As for the original issue (for completeness' sake), remove the square brackets from around `[User]` in the SQL in your first line.

Comment: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Comment: @Garrith Graham, OK, that doesn't appear to be MySQL syntax.  Any line number given in that error?

Comment: @Garrith Graham, try replacing "{1}" with "{0}".  "{1}" tells Format to look for the 2nd value you're passing, not the first.